# Understanding Moshe's use of his staff

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, va-eira, aharon

When Moshe came to Pharaoh and Pharaoh asked for an os (a sign), Moshe told Aaron to throw down the staff and it became a snake - [Shemos 7:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0).

There is an apparent machlokes meforshim as to whose staff it actually was.

The [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.7.9.1?lang=bi) writes that Aaron threw down the staff of Moshe and he proves it because Hashem instructed that Aaron should hit the river with the staff that became a snake. Then, later on in Rephidim, Hashem told Moshe to use his own staff which was the same one that was used to hit the river so it had to be that Moshe gave Aaron his staff to hit the river - so too here, it must have been Moshe's staff. We also have a proof from [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.17.5.3?vhe=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang=bi) in Beshalach where Hashem told Moshe to take his staff to hit the rock because up until now everyone was saying this staff was only used for punishments such as on Pharaoh, the makkos, and the yam suf. Thus, Hashem wanted Moshe to use the same one to bring water and we know the staff used on the yam suf was for sure Moshe’s as the posuk there ([Shemos 14:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.14.16?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) says explicitly, so it had to be Moshe’s same staff.

On the other hand, the [Netziv](https://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Davar_on_Exodus.7.9.2?lang=bi) says that there were really two staffs, the staff of Moshe and the staff of Aaron and this one was the one of Aaron. The Netziv proves this because with the makkah of dam (blood), Hashem tells Moshe to take the staff that was changed into a snake, and we know that the one in front of Pharaoh turned into a snake and therefore there must have been two different staffs. The Netziv says this is what troubled Rashi when he explained the word "תנין" to mean a snake because he held there was only one staff, that of Moshe’s. However, the Netziv argues because we know a "תנין" and a "נחש" are two different things, one being an alligator type creature and one a snake. As a result, he says it must be that there were two and at the makkah of dam Hashem told Moshe to take his even though Aaron would be the one hitting it with his own.

The question then becomes what was the need for Moshe to simply bring along his staff? The Netziv answers this by saying Aaron’s hit only turned the river into appearing like blood and Moshe hit it afterwards making it into blood itself. **The question we have on this is how could Moshe have done this if we know he was unable to hit it since he had to be makir tov (grateful) for the Nile saving him?** (Refer to [Rashi, Shemos 7:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.7.19.1?ven=Rashi_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) (Maybe it’s possible to answer that after it appeared like blood there was no longer an issue of not being makir tov.)

Comment: Rashi holds that Moshe had to be makir tov, but Rashi also holds there was one staff. Does the netziv hold that Moshe couldn't do the makka because he had to be makir tov? He might disagree there as well

Comment: Maybe of interest: refer to the [Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.869.3?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach&lang=bi) where it explains that it was one staff,  passed down from generation to generation (Shivlei Pinchas, Parshas Shemos, 5781).

Comment: Thanks @Shmuel I am aware of the Midrash

Comment: Can you explain pls netziv’s approach again I’m a little confused